# filter datatable by collectionview Exception "Specified method is not supported."

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to filter my data table by collectionView.

I tried this Code:

```
    private MaterialTableAdapter materialTableAdapter = new MaterialTableAdapter();
    private CollectionView viewSource;

public PgMaterials()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IMDataSet.MaterialDataTable mdt = materialTableAdapter.GetData();
        this.mainGrd.DataContext = mdt;
        viewSource = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mdt);
        viewSource.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        viewSource.Filter = FilterResults;
    }

    private bool FilterResults(object obj)
    {
        //(Ignore spaces). 
        string name = (obj as IMDataSet.MaterialRow).Name.Replace(" ", "");
        string searchedString = textBox.Text.Replace(" ", "");

        return (name.Contains(searchedString));
    }

 private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewSource.Refresh();
    }
```

But when i run the app it throws the following Exception:

> Specified method is not supported.

Comment: Don't use `System.Data` classes in WPF. Create a proper strongly typed data model instead.

Comment: But i have created all my project based on dataTable.
How can i do this?